# Where does the value of the variable in the subclass go?

Tags: python

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def f(self, x):
        return 2*x

    def g(self, x):
        return self.f(x)
        
class B(A):
    def g(self, y):
        return 3*y + self.x

class C1(B):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        B.__init__(self,x)
        self.y = y

    def f(self, x):
        return self.x + self.y

class C2(B):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        B.__init__(self,x)
        self.y = y

    def f(self, x):
        return x + self.x + self.y

a = A(5)
b = B(2)
c1 = C1(3,5)
c2 = C2(3,5)
```

When I do "What does the expression c2.f(4) evaluate to?", I was not sure where self.x in the f function in class C2 points to.

Could you give me some suggestions?

Comment: It points to x in class A. `self.x` will be 3

Comment: so can I assume that "B.__init__(self,x)" means "self.x=x"?

Comment: `B` doesn't have its own `__init__()` function, so the function on its superclass (A) gets called, which sets `self.x = x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c2.f(4)` makes 12. The value of x in function `f` is 4 because that is the argument in `c2.f(4)`. The value of c2's `self.x` is 3 because `C2` inherits from `B`, which inherits from `A`, where the line `self.x = x` occurs. In this line, `x` is what is entered in the line `c2 = C2(3,5)` and because it is assigned to `self.x`, `c2`'s `self.x` is 3. Because of the line `self.y = y` in class `C2`, the instance `c2`'s y value is what is entered in the line `c2 = C2(3,5)`, 5. 4 + 3 + 5 makes 12.